# Get Type of Capture Lambda at Compile Time

Tags: c++, lambda, compile-time

I'm trying to create a class static map of capture lambdas, but having some difficulty getting the type at compile time, to feed into the map template.

this is the lambda signature...

```
[=] (const uint8_t *buffer, const size_t bufferSize) -> void 
                                                         { 
                                                            //stuff 
                                                         };
```

And I'm trying to store in a map like so...

```
constexpr static auto generateExampleLambda(void) {

   auto lambda = [=] (const uint8_t *buffer, const size_t bufferSize) -> void 
                                                         { 
                                                            //stuff 
                                                         };

   return lambda;
}

constexpr static inline auto exampleLambda = generateExampleLambda();
constexpr typedef decltype(exampleLambda) LambdaType;
static inline std::unordered_map<uint16_t, LambdaType> callbacks;
```

But obviously this doesn't compile. I've got it working with no capture, but of course that's the easy case lol.

Comment: `{ //stuff };` The end bracket is being commented out.

Comment: @Rietty just an error in the way I wrote it in. I'll fix it. In the real code theres code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, every single lambda has his type.

To make it evident, you can verify that

```
auto l1 = []{};
auto l2 = []{};

static_assert( false == std::is_same_v<decltype(l1), decltype(l2)>, "!" );
// ............^^^^^
```

So I don't think it's possible to create a map for different lambdas with the type of the lambda.

The best I can imagine is insert the lambdas (more than one) in some `std::function<void(const uint8_t, const size_t)>` and make `callbacks` a

```
std::unordered_map<uint16_t, std::function<void(const uint8_t, const size_t)>>
```

Comment: I played around before with runtime type printing and saw that they each had unique types, but couldn't believe that was the case... as it makes 0 sense. I guess I'll have to stick to std::function until the committee fixes this ridiculous situation -- was just hoping to avoid the indirection of std::function, and gain the clarity of type.

Comment: @Gukki5 - maybe someone else can suggest a better way; but the use of `std::function` is the best I can imagine (at the moment, at least).

Comment: @Gukki5 I would say it makes perfect sense that they have different types. It's just syntactic sugar for creating a stand-alone class with an `operator()`. If lambdas with same signature shared same type it's hard to see how that would be implemented (without runtime cost).

Comment: @Gukki5 There are cheaper abstractions then `std::function`, but they can from what I know not store the callable object. It needs to live somewhere else.